# Docker - запуск нескольких python скриптов с помощью одного образа

Tags: linux, docker, администрирование, dockerfile

Имеется сервер, на котором стоит Docker, и проект из нескольких python-скриптов, которые обязательно должны запускаться по-отдельности, их нельзя запустить вместе через exec

Структура папок примерно такая:

```
- project
    - scripts 1
        - app.py
    - scripts 2
        - app.py
    - scripts-demo
        - app.py
    - docker
        - Dockerfile
        - requirements.txt
```

Я хочу с помощью `Dockerfile` создать простой образ (`image`), в котором будет `python 3.8` и библиотеки, которые находятся в `requirements.txt`. И чтобы в дальнейшем я мог примерно так запускать контейнер для каждого `app.py`:

```
docker run [путь до скрипта] [название образа] -it --restart=always
```

Сейчас мой `Dockerfile` такой:

```
FROM python:3.8

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

Обратите внимание, тут нет `CMD`, так как мне не нужно ничего запускать на этом этапе, мне нужно только чтобы был образ `python 3.8` с нужными мне библиотеками

После `build` создается образ, как мне и нужно, проблема возникает на этапе попытки запуска скрипта в контейнере с этим образом. Я попробовал запустить так:

```
docker run -v root/project/scripts 1/:/dir/ python /dir/app.py -it --restart=always
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/dir/app.py": permission denied: unknown.
```

Как я понял ему не хватает прав для запуска скрипта, но решения не нашел в гугле, пробовал и через chmod делать, и через групповую политику. Мне кажется я при самой настройке где-то накосячил, но в докере очень плохо разбираюсь и не понимаю где она

Comment: Также, я понимаю что можно к каждому app.py в папку прикрутить Dockerfile с CMD, и тогда всё работает без проблем, но каждый такой образ весит по 1.2гб, не хочется их плодить, да и как-то некрасиво и нелогично

Comment: «каждый такой образ весит по 1.2гб» — не забывайте о том, что если делать несколько образов на основе одного и того же базового образа, то этот базовый образ будет один общий для всех, то есть не будет копироваться и не будет занимать лишнее место

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD целевой python находится в `/usr/local/bin`, поэтому изначальный рецепт с запуском `/usr/bin/python3` был неверным.

Вам нужно запускать не скрипт, а `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Я бы делал так.

1. Сначала создал свой образ для контейнера из `Dockerfile`:

   ```sh
   docker build -t my-python ./docker/
   ```
2. Затем прописал все сервисы в `docker-compose.yaml`:

   ```
   version: '3'

   services:
     app1:
       image: my-python
       command: /usr/local/bin/python3 /dist/app.py
       restart: always
       volumes:
         - "./app1/:/dist"

     app2:
       image: my-python
       command: /usr/local/bin/python3 /dist/app.py
       restart: always
       volumes:
         - "./app2/:/dist"
   ```
3. И запустил бы всё разом командой `docker compose up`

Но если вам действительно нужно запускать контейнеры поштучно вручную, то команда такая:

```sh
docker run -it -v $PWD/app1:/dir --restart=always my-python \
       /usr/local/bin/python3 /dir/app
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Попробую завтра ;)

Comment: У меня сработало, но при запуске скрипта питон выдает ошибку, что не установлен модуль schedule, хотя у меня он указан в requirements.txt, не знаете, с чем это может быть связано? Я дополнил вопрос выше

Comment: Ага, с этим `/usr/bin/python3` вы вы всё немножко [сломали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1559178)

Comment: @andreymal ну кто бы мог подумать!

Comment: @WAYKS сорри, что ввёл вас в заблуждение. Я не ожидал, что в полном дистрибутиве несколько версий пайтона.

Comment: Я бы поставил ещё ENTRYPOINT на /usr/local/bin/python3, чтобы не писать этот путь каждый раз при запуске...