# В Docker-образе Python не видится установленная библиотека

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

У меня есть `Dockerfile`, из которого я создаю образ:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /root/scripts

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

А это `requirements.txt`:

```
schedule==1.2.0
```

Сборка:

```
docker build . -t my-python
```

Образ устанавливается без ошибок, если ввести `docker images`, то образ показывается в списке

Далее у меня есть файл `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  amoRU:
    image: my-python
    command: /usr/bin/python3 /dist/amoRU.py
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "./amoCRM/amoRU/:/dist"
```

Запускаю его командой:

```
docker compose up
```

И получаю ошибку об отсутствии модуля `schedule`, который импортируется в начале файла `amoRU.py`. Сам файл он видит, проблема именно в образе

Как мне проверить вообще установился ли он в образ изначально: когда происходит `build`, не успеваю заметить, все очень быстро происходит? Может быть, я как-то не так указываю `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Как запускаете-то?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Про «как мне проверить» рекомендую освоиться с [чтением логов сборки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37832575) и с запуском произвольных команд в образе (через [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)) или в уже запущенном контейнере (через [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)). Запуск шелла я показал в ответе, но также можно сразу запустить питон для проверки: `docker run -it my-python /usr/local/bin/python3 -c 'import schedule'` — работает, `docker run -it my-python /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import schedule'` — не работает

Comment: (ах да, если забыть опцию `--rm`, то каждый такой `docker run` оставляет после себя контейнеры... Можно удалить их командой `docker container prune`)

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал использовать в качестве базового образа `python:3.8-slim`. Его размер 128 мб против 998 мб образа `python:3.8`. И в нём точно всего один `python` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Прикол в том, что в образе `python:3.8` [два разных питона](https://hub.docker.com/_/python):

> In the non-slim variants there will be an additional (distro-provided) `python` executable at `/usr/bin/python` (and/or `/usr/bin/python3`) while the desired image-provided `/usr/local/bin/python` is the default choice in the `$PATH`.

Заходим в шелл вашего образа и смотрим:

```
$ docker run -it my-python /bin/sh
# /usr/local/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.8.18
# /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.11.2
```

Вы установили все библиотеки для питона 3.8 (команда `pip` соответствует `/usr/local/bin/pip`), а запускать скрипт пытаетесь через `/usr/bin/python3`, который запускает дебиановый питон 3.11.

Что можно предпринять для решения:

1. Запускать правильный питон — уберите полный путь вообще, чтобы нашёлся правильный питон из `$PATH`: `command: python3 /dist/amoRU.py`
2. Заменить базовый образ на другой, в котором будет только один питон: `FROM python:3.8-slim` — имейте в виду, что в нём `/usr/bin/python3` не существует и есть только `/usr/local/bin/python3` (но, как я упомянул выше, лучше написать просто `python3` без полного пути)

Comment: Интересно, я думал в образе питона лежит только заявленный питон, зачем они ещё один более свежий кладут, не очень понятно. Многие небось путаются. )

Comment: @CrazyElf видимо они не специально, следствие использования дебиана в качестве базы (и там по ссылке написано что-то про «we can't safely remove/overwrite it»)

Comment: Спасибо! Интересно конечно сделано, ну, главное получилось разобраться)

Comment: @andreymal А, ну вот "не можем выпилить из системы" - это логично.

Comment: @CrazyElf для продакшена обычно используются `*-slim` образы. В них таких приколов нет: в `python:3.8-slim` ровно один `python`, как написал andreymal.